# When I pyramid a second "long" entry order, how can I move the stop-loss of the first entry order to match the second stop-loss?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

When I pyramid a second "long" entry order using Pine Script on TradingView, how can I move the stop-loss of the first entry order *to match the second stop-loss level?*

I'm pretty comfortable with coding single-entry trading systems, but could you give me an example of how I can amend this code to "shift" the first stop-loss order up to match the stop-loss level of the second entry position?

```
//@version=5 
//Daily Chart
//Trading Long and Short
//20 period Donchian entry (4-week).  
//10 period Donchian exit (2-week). 
//2*ATR initial stop-loss from close.

//Can pyramid to have a maximum of 2 open positions.  A new position is opened when the price closes above 2*ATR 
//from the initial entery. A new position is opened with another 2*ATR stop loss, and the stop losses of any previous 
//position is are raised up to match the new stop loss level.

strategy(" P Turtles S1",overlay=true, initial_capital=100000,currency=currency.GBP, process_orders_on_close = true, pyramiding = 2)

//Inputs
OpenPositionDonchLength=input.int(title="OpenPositionDonchLength",defval=20,step=5)
ClosePositionDonchLength=input.int(title="ClosePositionDonchLength",defval=10,step=5)
ATRLength=input.int(title="ATR Length", defval=20,step=1)
ATRMultiple=input.int(title="ATR Multiple",defval=2,step=1)
RiskPercentage=input.float(title="Risk %", defval=2,step=0.5)

//Variables
LongTrigger=ta.highest(close[1],OpenPositionDonchLength)
CloseLong=ta.lowest(close[1],ClosePositionDonchLength)
ShortTrigger=ta.lowest(close[1],OpenPositionDonchLength)
CloseShort=ta.highest(close[1],ClosePositionDonchLength)
ATRLongStop=close-(ATRMultiple*ta.atr(ATRLength))
ATRShortStop=close+(ATRMultiple*ta.atr(ATRLength))

//Plot
plot(LongTrigger,"Long Trigger", color.green)
plot(CloseLong,"Exit Long", color.green)
plot(ShortTrigger,"Short Trigger", color.red)
plot(CloseShort,"Exit Short", color.red)
plot(ATRLongStop, "ATR Long Stop", color.yellow)
plot(ATRShortStop, "ATR Short Stop", color.orange)

//Entry Conditions
EnterL1=close>LongTrigger  
EnterL2=close>(strategy.opentrades.entry_price(1) + (ATRMultiple*ta.atr(ATRLength)))

EnterS1=close<ShortTrigger 
EnterS2=close<(strategy.opentrades.entry_price(1) - (ATRMultiple*ta.atr(ATRLength)))

// Calculate position size
RiskEquity=(0.1*RiskPercentage)*strategy.equity
RiskPerTrade=EnterL1 or EnterL2 ?((close-ATRLongStop)*syminfo.pointvalue):((ATRShortStop-close)*syminfo.pointvalue)
PosSize=RiskEquity/RiskPerTrade

//Entry orders
if strategy.position_size==0
    if EnterL1 
        strategy.entry("EL1",strategy.long,qty=PosSize)
        strategy.exit (id="LS1", stop=ATRLongStop)
    if EnterL2 and EnterL1 
        strategy.entry("EL2",strategy.long,qty=PosSize)
        strategy.exit (id="LS2", stop=ATRLongStop)

if strategy.position_size==0
    if EnterS1 
        strategy.entry("ES1",strategy.short,qty=PosSize)
        strategy.exit (id="SS1", stop=ATRLongStop)
    if EnterS2 and EnterL1 
        strategy.entry("ES2",strategy.short,qty=PosSize)
        strategy.exit (id="SS2", stop=ATRLongStop)

//Exit all open positions - condition is:
ExitLong=close<CloseLong
ExitShort=close>CloseShort

if ExitLong
    strategy.close_all("Exit Long")

if ExitShort
    strategy.close_all("Exit Short")
```

Many thanks, David.